# Turning off "Inherit permissions from higher levels" programmatically

Tags: permissions, plone, zope

I am trying to setup some group maintained folders that should not be seen by the other groups.  Currently, I achieve that by un-clicking the "Inherit permissions from higher levels" check-box in the @@sharing tab, but I would like to automate this.

I could not find anything about this in the documentation or googling.  After searching around the eggs directory I found some interesting things about 'ac_inherited_permissions' but nothing jumped out at me as my solution.

I'd like to do something like obj.inherited_permissions = False, or call whichever function I need to.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sharing tab only affects local roles. These usually are inherited from parents (acquired), but you can explicitly block these by setting `__ac_local_roles_block__` to `True` on an object.

Make sure, however, you set this on the unwrapped object (no acquisition context):

```
from Acquisition import aq_base

aq_base(object).__ac_local_roles_block__ = True
```

Comment: I thought it would be something like that.  Thank you!

Comment: Martijn, would you mind elaborating on the warning about using aq_base?

Comment: @cewing: In this case, it's actually redundant; setting an attribute always does so on the current object (it won't walk up the chain to find the attribute elsewhere and set it there). But explicit is better than implicit, and when *retreaving* the attribute to check if it is set, you definitely want to look at `aq_base` (for this particular attribute). Hence the explicit unwrapping.